# Count a specific event occurring within the same minute for 5 or more than 5 times

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have column A which has the word "Client rebooted" and "lockup".

I have another column B which gives me the date and time rounded off to the nearest minute of the corresponding events (i.e "client rebooted" or "lockup").

I am trying to figure out a way to count the word "Client rebooted" occurring 5 or more times within the exact same minute of the same day. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pivot table to help you. Go to `Insert` > `Insert PivotTable` and drag the headers `Event` to "Row Lables" and "Values", and `Time` to "Row Labels" like so:

[image]

You can then put a filter by selecting column E and inserting a filter, then filter on numbers above 4 (or equal to or greater than 5)

If you click in the pivot table and go to the pane 'Design' > 'Subtotals' > 'Do not show subtotals', you will not see the `12` or `8` in the pivotable below, thus making the filtering easier. You can also collapse `lockup` by clicking on the little <kbd>-</kbd> button right next to it if you want (but the subtotal will reappear).

Comment: You sir are a genius!! Works like a charm. I am sooooo thankful to you. I will keep working on it and will post any further questions that I have regarding the same. Again. Thanks a ton!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @UdayBhagavatula You're welcome! x3 And sure, so send your questions if you have any more on this! I'll try to answer them asap

Comment: The method given previously by you was fantastic. I am trying to run a "Countifs" sort of a formula if there is any that is. Something which goes this way:- countifs(A:A, 'client rebooted", B:B, "5 or more occurring within the same minute" . Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks!!!

Comment: @UdayBhagavatula Hmm, I'm not sure it'll be 'elegant' since you can have _any_ time! You could however use `COUNTIFS` as you describe like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hYMCw.png). You'll then have to filter on column A and C to get the criteria required. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Well. I actually have about 60 different workbooks with 10 tabs each with the same formatting and a couple of other formulas running which in turn is linked to some other data. I have already populated the data in all of them and I am now trying to make a modification. So I was just attempting to save a bit of time by using a direct formula like "Countifs" instead. I wish I could explain better. But I guess you are right. I can use the countifs formula the way you described. Thank you so much Jerry!!!

Answer (score 2):

For a formula approach you can use FREQUENCY function like this

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A100="Client rebooted",B2:B100),B2:B100)>5,1))`

that's an array formula that need to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> so that curly braces like { and } appear around the formula in the formula bar

Comment: @ barry Thank you so much for your response. I tried the formula but it does not show the correct result .Is it possible for you to explain the formula by breaking it down? Maybe I am missing something here. That will help me understand my mistake and could tweak it accordingly. Your help is highly highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER?

Comment: Further I am trying to group it in terms of hourly intervals...Say between...12 PM to 4 PM, 4PM to 8PM so on and so forth...This is in addition to the first part..

Comment: I double clicked on the formula and then used CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: To test the formula I had "client rebooted" in column A for about 12 times and in column B, I had "2:51 PM" in a time readable format 12 times. Ideally the result should have been 12. But it shows 1 as the result. When I changed "1" in the formula to "2", the result shows as "2"

Comment: The result is 1 because there is only one time which repeats more than 5 times, do you want 12 as the result - assuming matching criteria too if there are 3 matching times with counts of 4, 5, 6 respectively what result do you want?

Comment: so here's the logic...If there are 5 or more than 5 "client reboots" at the exact same time on the same day, then that translates into 5 or more "power events". Like I described above, I want 12 as the result if there are 12 client reboots at the exact same time. So, I can translate this result into 12 "Power events" now because there are 5 or more "cLIENT REBOOTS" at the exact same MINUTE. I am sorry I hope I was clearer this time. Thanks!